# How can I go back to previous code in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I'm pretty new to programming, but I've got a quick question. I'm trying to write a sort of "choose your own adventure" game, but I've run into a problem. I'm only really as far into `if` statements in the code, but I want to be able to send the user back to previous code when they type something.

For example:

```
print "You are in a room with two doors to either side of you."
choiceOne = raw_input("Which way will you go?")
choiceOne = choiceOne.lower()
if choiceOne = "r" or choiceOne = "right":
     print "You go through the right door and find yourself at a dead end."
elif choiceOne = "l" or choiceOne = "left":
     print "You go through the left door and find yourself in a room with one more door."
else:
     print "Please choose left or right."
```

In the `if` statement, I want to send the user back to `choiceOne`'s `raw_input()`. In the `elif` statement, I want to give the user the option to either proceed through the next door, or return to the first room to see what secrets the other door may hold. Is there any way to do this? I don't care if the way is complicated or whatever, I just want to get this working.

Comment: You'll be wanting to read about "control flow", such as the while loop.

Comment: Have a look here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: do you have another function to proceed through to the next door?

Comment: Also have a look at this tutorial sections: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: I can see a problem with your question: Either you need help with basic control flow statements, then you should read the Python tutorial first, then reduce your question to the core problem (I guess the tutorial will clear things up already); or you want to write an adventure game, then you should definitely read up on game design and then ask on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com:) A (text) game has to keep the state of many objects including the player -- this is a very complex topic! If you like text adventures then read about [inform](http://inform-fiction.org/manual/DM4.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop?

I think that this website explains it very well: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

[image]

```
count = 0
while (count < 9):
   print 'The count is:', count
   count = count + 1

print "Good bye!"
```

→

```
The count is: 0
The count is: 1
The count is: 2
The count is: 3
The count is: 4
The count is: 5
The count is: 6
The count is: 7
The count is: 8
Good bye!
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    print "You are in a room with two doors to either side of you."
    choice_one = raw_input("Which way will you go?").lower()
    if choice_one == "r" or choice_one == "right":
         print "You go through the right door and find yourself at a dead end."
         continue # go back to choice_one 
    elif choice_one == "l" or choice_one == "left":
         print "You go through the left door and find yourself in a room with one more door."
         choice_two = raw_input("Enter 1 return the the first room or 2 to proceed to the next room")
         if choice_two == "1":
            # code go to first room
         else:
             # code go to next room
    else:
         print "Please choose left or right."
```

You need to use `==` for a comparison check, `=` is for assignment.

To break the loop you could add a print outside the loop `print "Enter e to quit the game"`:

Then in your code add:

```
elif choice_one == "e":
        print "Goodbye"
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm pretty new, so I appreciate you helping me out with syntax and stuff.

Comment: no worries, you should probably handle cases where the user inputs incorrect data and give them the option to quit the game by breaking the loop